# How can I calculate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

> How can I calculate this limit?
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}$$

I thought about L'Hospital because case of $\frac{0}{0}$, but I don't know how to contiune from this point..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: have you tried Hospital ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But I don't have idea how to go about it. I just think that it's can be with L'Hospital(but I don't know how to do it even with L'Hospital)..

Comment: Where's the $n$ in the function your are trying to calculate?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: that correspond to the derivative at zero of $(1+x)^{1/x}$

Comment: @5xum I edited it..

Comment: @MathQues What did you get after applying L'Hospital?

Comment: @5xum I get in trouble when I try to cut the numerator ..

Comment: @MathQues So you are saying you are having trouble calculating the derivative of the numerator?

Comment: @5xum yes, exactly. But now while I see the answer by "Guy Fsone" which used taylor, it's looks so beautiful.

Comment: @MathQues It's also possible to do it without Taylor (see my answer), but yeah, I agree that's the most elegant way.

Comment: Approach0 [returns a few questions](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim%5Climits_%7Bx%5Cto%200%5E%2B%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7B(1%2Bx)%5E%7B1%2Fx%7D%20-e%7D%7Bx%7D%24&p=1) about the same limit: [Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105685), [How to solve this limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447429), [Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} - e}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/920132), 
...

Comment: ... [How to compute $\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1\over x}-e}{x}$ without using a series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1364171),
[Solving a limit with taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033603),
[Need hint for $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x+1)^\frac{1}{x}-e}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1101831),
Find the limit: $\lim_\limits{x\to 0}{\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{1/x}-e}{x}}$,
[Limit as $x\to 0$ of $\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556766).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\ln(x+1)= x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)~~~and ~~~e^x= 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$
we get
$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}= \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)\right) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{x}(x-\frac{x^2}{2} +O(x^3))\right) \\=\exp\left(1-\frac{x}{2} +O(x^2)\right) =e\exp\left(-\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)\right) = e(1- \frac{x}{2}+O(x^2))  $$

Hence $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e(1- \frac{x}{2}+O(x^2))-e}{x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} -\frac{e}{2}+O(x) = \color{blue}{-\frac{e}{2}}$$

Comment: Hye guy, thank you very much for your full answer, it's clear and so beautiful!

Comment: If you are using big-O or little-o notation, you can use '$=$' instead of '$\sim$'.

Comment: @robjohn thanks that is right as synthaxe precision

Answer (score 2):

let $n = \frac 1x$

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} n((1+\frac 1n)^n - e)$

Binomial expansion:

$n(1 + 1 + \frac 12 (1-\frac 1n) + \frac 1{3!} (1-\frac 1n)(1-\frac 2{n})+\cdots +\frac {1}{n!} (1-\frac 1n)\cdots(1-\frac {n-1}{n}) - e)$

$e = 1 + 1 + \frac 1{2!} + \frac {1}{3!}\cdots$

$n( (-\frac 12  -\frac 1{3!} {3\choose 2} - \frac 1{4!} {4\choose 2} -\cdots - - \frac 1{n!} {n\choose 2})\frac 1{n} + o(\frac 1{n^2}))\\
-\frac 12(1+1+\frac 12 + \frac 1{3!}\cdots \frac {1}{n!}) + o(\frac 1n)\\
-\frac 12 e$

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital is one way to go here if you don't have knowledge of Taylor series yet.

The only tricky derivative is probably the derivative of $(1+x)^{\frac1x}$,  which you can more easily calculate as

$$\left((1+x)^{\frac1x}\right)' = \left(e^{\frac1x\ln(1+x)}\right)' = e^{\frac1x\ln(1+x)} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)} - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\right) = (1+x)^{\frac1x}\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)} - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\right)$$

Given that the first expression, $(1+x)^{\frac1x}$, has a limit of $e$, you only need to find the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)} - \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\right)$$ which is doable with a couple more applications of L'Hospital.

Comment: But now the last limit is diverges, because that while $x \to 0^{+}$ so it's $\infty$ and while $x \to 0^{-}$ so it's -$\infty$ . No?

Comment: while $x \to 0^{+}$ so I get $\infty - 1 = \infty$, and while $x \to 0^{-}$ so I get $ - \infty - 1 = - \infty$. No?

Comment: @MathQues Sorry, there was an $x^2$ instead of an $x$ there. I fixed it now.

Comment: oh, ok, it's beautiful too, the trick is to work with $e^{ln(f(x))}=f(x)$.. If I could, I would make you upvote (i have just 13 reputations).  Thank you!!!

Comment: @MathQues Yes, the main trick is the same here as in the accepted answer, and the same as if you want to calculate the derivative of $F(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$ in general: $F(x)=e^{F(x)} = e^{g(x)\ln(f(x))}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x} =& \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(1/x\ln(1+x))-e}{x}= e\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(1/x\ln(1+x)-1)-1}{x} &\\=& e\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(1/x\ln(1+x)-1)-1}{1/x\ln(1+x)-1 } \dfrac{1/x\ln(1+x)-1}{x}&\\=&e\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}  \dfrac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2} &\\=& -\dfrac{e}{2}\end{align}$$

Limits used :

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$, $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\ln(x+1)-x}{x^2} = \dfrac{-1}{2}$

[Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion) for the derivation of third limit without 
 LH rule and series.

Answer (score 1):

By the generalized binomial theorem,

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=1+\frac1xx+\frac1x\left(\frac1x-1\right)\frac{x^2}2+\frac1x\left(\frac1x-1\right)\left(\frac1x-2\right)\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\\
=1+1+\frac{1-x}{2}+\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)}{3!}++\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)}{4!}\cdots$$

Clearly, the constant term is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}=e.$$

Then the first degree coefficient is

$$-\frac12-\frac{1+2}{3!}-\frac{1+2+3}{4!}-\cdots=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(k-1)k}2\frac1{k!}=-\frac e2.$$

Answer (score 1):

By inequality

$$x-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq \log (1+x) \leq x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}$$

$$1-\frac{x}{2}\leq \frac{\log (1+x)}{x} \leq 1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}$$

we have that

$$e^{1-\frac{x}{2}}\leq (1+x)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\frac{\log (1+x)}{x}} \leq e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}} $$

thus

$$-\frac{e}2\le\frac{e^{1-\frac{x}{2}}-e}{x}\leq \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x} \leq \frac{ e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}-e}{x}\to -\frac{e}2$$

indeed

$$ \frac{ e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}-e}{x} =e \cdot \frac{ e^{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}-1}{ -\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3} }\cdot\frac{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}}{x}\to e\cdot1\cdot -\frac12=-\frac{e}2$$

therefore for squeeze theorem

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}-e}{x}=-\frac{e}2$$

Answer (score -1):

I just would like to add one idea to what's already been said. When using L'Hospital, never be mechanic. And I don't mean just to test that you have the right kind of indetermination before each time you apply the rule (checking hypotheses is a must before using *any* theorem/property). But it is also useful to watch in detail the function you are taking limits to and try to figure out where the difficulty is, so you can work apart with that specific expression. Taking derivatives of everything is not always of help; and it's better if you take the control of all those formulas instead the other way around.

For instance, the first time you use L'Hospital here you get the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \quad (1+x)^{\tfrac1x}\cdot \frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}.$$
I put the first factor separate on purpose, because that one tends to $e$, while in the fraction both numerator and denominator go to $0$. Since the first factor bring no trouble, most of the times the better thing will be to leave it there and work separately with the quotient. Even more, the $(1+x)$ in the denominator is not what makes it $0$, so we could actually move it away too (and maybe cancel it with another $(1+x)$ from $(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}$).

So it's better to work with 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2},$$
where we can use L'Hospital again: once you know where this tends to, you can put it together with the rest.

If you go on, you'll have again a similar situation, and so it will be important to think how you write things and what part you leave aside, too.

Of course, never forget to collect all the partial results at the end in order to give the solution of the original problem. (Yes, it's very easy to make such mistakes when you're nervous or short of time. =S)